# Ransack cyrillic (russian) case insensitive search on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use `field_name_cont`. This predicate works fine with Latin charset on production, but it's case sensitive with Cyrillic. On my local machine this works fine with both of them. How to find what is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres encoding on my production was SQL-ASCII. Postgres on my development machine was UTF-8. After Postgres encoding was changed to UTF-8 everything works well.